# C++: How member binary plus operator works?

Tags: c++, binary, overloading, operator-keyword, member

We have a class (assuming there are some operations in functions, but constructor is default):

```
class X
{
public:
    X& operator=(const X& rhs){}
    const X& operator+(const X& rhs) const {}
    const X& operator+(int m) {}
}; 
X a, b, c;
```

**Q1**: Why is `a = a + 5 + c;` allowed and `a = b + c + 5;` is not? We have:

> Error C2679   binary '+': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

**Q2**: Why `(c = a + a) = b + c;` begins with b+c operation and not with a+a? (I found that out while debugging).

P.S. It's theoretical question only.

Comment: `(c = a + a) = b + c;` is undefined behavior as you are reading and writing to to the same variable in a single sequence point.

Comment: offtopic: why your `operator+` returns `&` ? I found a great example of operators overloading in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719)

Comment: @NathanOliver, in Visual Studio it at least executes fine. The question was, why such order?

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych, i found that example while doing some C++ tests, so i can't really answer the question)

Comment: I see no logic in making the addition operator affects the original object. It should add add some member data of the tow objects and return the result at return. So `x = a + b` who will be affected is `x` not a nor `b`. `int a = 5, b = 7, c = 0; c  = a + b;` so `c` is `12` and `a` and `b` are not affected. This is what you should take in count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is a = a + 5 + c; allowed and a = b + c + 5; is not?

const X& operator+(int m) {}  is not a const function, and the return from the + operators is const X.  Make this a const function and it'll work fine; (apart from returning a reference after this operation is very strange)

Comment: I tried it and it really works! I still don't get it... How making function a const influence operator calling?

Comment: `const X& operator+(int m) {}` this function says that it will change the X that it's going to be operating on - meaning it can't be done on a const object.
`const X& operator+(const X& rhs) const {}` this function says that it will return a const X&